# Unable to select Values for X-axis of a Powerpoint line chart

Tags: c#, powerpoint, vsto, office-interop, excel-interop

I have developed a powerpoint plugin to insert a line chart with markers
This chart number of hours worked on each day for a given week.
Program first adds a chart to a slide using [AddChart2](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/powerpoint.shapes.addchart2).
Then adds data in the worksheet attached to the chart :

[image: Weekly data for number of hours worked each day]

I have created a Series object. I am using below code to select the range of XValues

```
 Series week1 = chartSeriesCollection.NewSeries();
 week1.Name = "WEEK-1";
 week1.XValues = chartWorkSheet.Range[chartWorkSheet.Cells[2, 1],chartWorkSheet.Cells[7,1]];
 week1.Values = chartWorkSheet.Range[chartWorkSheet.Cells[2, 2],chartWorkSheet.Cells[7,2]];
```

Plugin gives exception on line 3 (i.e. where I assign week1.XValues)

```
System.Runtime.InteropServices.COMException: 'Type mismatch. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x80020005 (DISP_E_TYPEMISMATCH))'
```

What is a correct way to select XValues?
I am unable to find a C# example that helps to resolve above issue.

Comment: @jonrsharpe : Thank you for pruning the content and making it more readable

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Solution**:

I was assigning a range of cells, instead of values inside them, to the XValues and that caused Type Mismatch error.

I fixed below lines :

```
week1.XValues = (chartWorkSheet.Range[chartWorkSheet.Cells[2, 1],chartWorkSheet.Cells[7,1]] as Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Range).Value;
week1.Values = (chartWorkSheet.Range[chartWorkSheet.Cells[2, 2],chartWorkSheet.Cells[7,2]] as Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Range).Value;
```